# How to align structure to specifed size

Tags: c++

I have header for my OpenGL texture format. I want to align struct size to 512 to add necessary members in the future. I've added before and after my struct `#pragma pack(push, 1)` `#pragma pack(pop)`. I mean align like filling (?) bootloader to 512 bytes.

**UPDATE:**
I've made some code on ideone. Here's it: http://ideone.com/CW0kY4.

Comment: You might try putting your entire structure into a `union` with a `char[512]` element.

Comment: Do you really mean "align", or just "pad to X bytes"?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a member to your struct which is called "Reserved" which is a an array of bytes. This makes the total size 512 bytes:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t Member1;
    uint8_t Member2;

    uint8_t Reserved[510]; // Reserved data for future use which is the remainder
} Data;
```

Alternatively you can use a nested struct that automatically calculates the size of the data in compile time:

```
typedef struct
{
    int Member1;
    int Member2;
} Data;

typedef struct
{
    Data TheData;
    uint8_t Reserved[512-sizeof(Data)];
} FullData;
```

Comment: This is really not particularly practical, given that you have to add up whatever size the OTHER elements are. Which isn't very hard in this case, but gets quite difficult if there are dozens of members that are of different sizes.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I updated the answer to have a solution for that as well.

Comment: Not that it necessarily detracts from the validity of the answer, but the first solution in this answer also assumes the size of `int` to be 32-bits, which is not necessarily guaranteed. `int`s are only guaranteed to be at least 16-bits. Consider using `int32_t` instead, Emil.

Comment: Yeah, it's just an example where I assume they are 4 bytes. I can make it simpler, and just make them into bytes.

Comment: I would add a `static_assert(sizeof(Data) == 512)` to protect against future modification errors.